# for loop logic porting from bash to csh

Tags: linux, bash, for, csh

I have below code snippet working in bash:

```
for i in `ps -eaf | grep -i <pattern> | awk '{print $3}'`; do kill -9 $i; done
```

But I have a requirement to port this code to work in csh shell due to some legacy application is written using csh.

Sample output of "ps -eaf | grep -i  | awk '{print $3}'"

```
5284

3543

14390

4811

4814
```

I am on RHEL 7.2 (tcsh-6.18.01-8.el7.x86_64, bash-4.2.46-19.el7.x86_64)

Comment: Hello, @dcds, you would like to get integer number frim where? Variable? Read it from a file?

Comment: Hi @Goro I will be getting process Ids by using some grep patterns.

Comment: would you please include example? this will be very helpful and  our answer will be more accurate, after `grep` are these ids saved in a file or just variables

Comment: Hi @Goro I have updated the question.

Comment: Not in text file . I just want to run on terminal.

Comment: would you please try the solution and let me know. We can tweak it for you as well ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach i (`echo 1 2 3`)
  echo $i
end
```

Using your example:

```
foreach i (`ps -eaf | grep -i <pattern> | awk '{print $3}'`)
  kill -9 $i
end
```

Comment: I want to run this in single line in terminal.

Comment: the run it with `xargs`, as the other answer suggested: `ps -eaf | grep -i <pattern> | awk '{print $3}' | xargs kill -9`. `foreach ... end` cannot be on a single line in `csh`.